# jquery hover over image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the `opacity` of the main `image` when the mouse `hover` on the `right` image simple as that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #main {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        #right {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: -310px;
            margin-top: 320px;
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        #center {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: -655px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#right").hover(function () {
                $("main").css("opacity","0.4");
                $("right").css("visibility","visible");
            }, function () {
                $("main").css("opacity","1");
                $("right").css("visibility","hidden");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="main" src="img/1477253.jpg">
<img id="right" src="img/Untitled-1.png">
<img id="center" src="img/Untitled-2.png">
</body>
</html>
```

but when the `mouse` get on the hidden `right` image nothing happen. what am missing here?

Comment: Why not use `#right:hover` CSS rule?

Comment: You can't hover `#right` because it's off the viewport and it's hidden also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it , instead of using `visibility: hidden;` I used `opacity: 0;` and this way it worked fine , thanks for the comments guys :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hover over a hidden element.You are binding event to `#right`
 which is `visibility:hidden`

change css properties of right to:

```
#right {
         position: absolute;
         margin-left: -310px;
         margin-top: 320px;
     }
```

now the element can be seen in DOM and `hover` event is triggered

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/lizuwuvahe/1/)

Comment: Thats right! To clarify: elements which are hidden won't cause any events to be fired so no handler will be used for there is no event to handle...

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the # id in the jQuery selector

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#right").hover(function () {
            $("#main").css("opacity","0.4");
            $("#right").css("visibility","visible");
        }, function () {
            $("#main").css("opacity","1");
            $("#right").css("visibility","hidden");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Couldn't type fast enough, you beat me. ha

Comment: This won't solve the problem. The problem is, that hidden elements won't trigger any events. So as long as the DOM-Element is hidden, no handler will be notified about occurring events

Comment: @serjoscha oops, you're right. it's obviously too early in the morning for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #main {
        opacity: 1;
    }

</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#right").hover(function () {
            $("#main").css("opacity","0.4");
            $("#right").css("visibility","visible");
        }, function () {
            $("#main").css("opacity","1");
            $("#right").css("visibility","hidden");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <img id="main" src="img/1477253.jpg" />
   <img id="right" src="img/1477253.jpg" />
   <img id="center" src="img/Untitled-2.png" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

Remove css class i.e `#right` and `#center` and see the result. Due to this class you are not able to see the image.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing # and hidden element means it is gone. You cannot get mouse hover on it. Use opacity 0 instead. Another point, your image position may not show image on the screen, except it is very large, so I comment it.

Here is the modified version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #main {
            opacity: 1.0;
        }

        #right {
            /*position: absolute;*/
            /*margin-left: -310px;*/
            /*margin-top: 320px;*/
            opacity: 0.0;
        }

        #center {
            /*position: absolute;*/
            /*margin-left: -655px;*/
            /*margin-top: 20px;*/
            opacity: 0.0;
        }
    </style>
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#right").hover(function () {
                $("#main").css("opacity","0.4");
                $("#right").css("opacity","1.0");
            }, function () {
                $("#main").css("opacity","1");
                $("#right").css("opacity","0.0");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="main" src="img/1477253.jpg">
<img id="right" src="img/Untitled-1.png">
<img id="center" src="img/Untitled-2.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #main {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        #right {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: -310px;
            margin-top: 320px;
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        #center {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: -655px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#right").hover(function () {
                $("#main").css("opacity","0.4");
                $("#right").css("visibility","visible");
            }, function () {
                $("#main").css("opacity","1");
                $("#right").css("visibility","hidden");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="main" src="img/1477253.jpg">
<img id="right" src="img/Untitled-1.png">
<img id="center" src="img/Untitled-2.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#right").mouseover(function () {
        $("#main").css("opacity", "0.4");
        $("#right").css("opacity", "1");
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $("#main").css("opacity", "1");
        $("#right").css("opacity", "0");
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonypagaycarbon/b9nsqda0/)**